# NOT condition not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have a **mysql table** with a **column** `jazyk_en` which has *value* `9` in the correct row.

I need to perform if action only if there is not value `9` so I am using this:

```
if ($_POST['jazyk'] == 'en' AND $jaz !== '9'){ 
    mysql_query("UPDATE user SET jazyk='en' where name='".$username."'");
}
```

When I display `$jaz` via `echo`, it really shows `9` but the mysql is still updated even though I added `$jaz !== '9'`.

I have even tried `$jaz < 5`, which would work for me as well. Still not working.

I am really desperate now because I don't see a reason why it shouldn't be working properly...

Do you know where the problem could be?

Thank you!

Comment: `!==` is PHP syntax. You're using MySQL. Two different animals altogether. What is the column type for it?

Comment: *"with a column `jazyk_en`"* and you're using `SET jazyk='en'`?

Comment: `$jazykaktivni_q = mysql_query("select * from user where name='".$username."'"); $jazykaktivni = mysql_fetch_array($jazykaktivni_q); $jaz = $jazykaktivni['jazyk_en'];` This is the code. The column type is varchar but I tried to change to another type as well. Still not working.

Comment: Yes, `jazyk_en` and `jazyk` are two different columns. I do not need to work with `jazyk` right now.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your method. This part is unclear `if ($_POST['jazyk'] == 'en' AND $jaz !== '9')`. If you want to check if a column does not equal a certain number, then you need to use that in a SELECT query first. You wrote below *"however when I get $jaz from the database, it is not working."* you need to show us the code related to that.

Comment: `$_POST['jazyk'] == 'en'` is from my form from another page. It works correctly, but if you want the code: Here it is: `<table class="tabulkajazyku"><tr><td><form id="myformen2" action="member" method="POST"><input type="hidden" name="jazyk" value="en"><a class="myclass" href="#" id="mylinken2"><img src="/images/flag_en.jpg" class="vlajky"><div class="posun5">EN</div></a></form></td></tr>More tr goes here...</table>` And regarding  `$jaz`I explained is above. It connects to mysql `mysql_query("select * from user where name='".$username."'");` This query goes first of course.

Comment: please don't drop code in comments.

Comment: Sorry, I just wanted to explain what you had asked me. You write that I need to show you the query code. It is in this thread. The third comment

Comment: You should remove the `AND $jaz !== '9'` from your first line and do 
`mysql_query("UPDATE user SET jazyk='en' where name='".$username." AND !='$jaz'");` instead. I'm pretty sure that will work. or remove the quotes in `AND !='$jaz'` as `AND !=$jaz` in the query if quotes do not work. But it should.

Comment: We probably do not understand each other. I need to perform the UPDATE only if `$jaz !== '9'` If I do the update first and put the condition in there, I guess it won't be what I am looking for.

Comment: Your select query is failing then. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: I can do that but as I have already mentioned: When I echo `$jaz`, it shows the correct number from the database so query must be working properly.

Comment: then the placement/ordering of your code is failing and probably how you're encapsulating conditionals. Not seeing how your entire code that you're using is structured, makes it impossible to answer/resolve. Good luck, I have to move on now. Ask the others that gave you answers below. I cannot guess as they are doing right now and I have voted to close your question, sorry but that's how things work here. We can't keep commenting back and forth like this, until you post your full code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

`...AND $jaz != '9')...` use only single `=` while comapring with `NOT EQUAL` `!=`

Comment: Thanks, but still not working. I used many combinations and no one works.

Comment: try assigning some new value and test the execution like `$jaz = 8;` and test.

Comment: When I type it directly to the code it works, however when I get `$jaz` from the database, it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `echo` to debug your php code, use `var_dump` instead

It allows you to show the type of your variable

Try

```
var_dump($jaz)
```

And show us the result

The `===` check if the value is the same but check if the type is the same too. The `==` only check the value but not the type.

**Example :**

```
'9' == 9 //true
'9' === 9 //false
```

Comment: It says `string(1) "9"`

Comment: That's why your comparaison is true (see my post). $jaz` is a string that contains the char '9' which is a string and not an integer. So $jaz IS DIFFERENT than 9 (integer). `'9' !== 9 //true`. So you should try : `$jaz != 9` without quote

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the below edit and also tell me which `column` is `value "9"` as of now i assume that the `value "9"` is an `id`, PS: you need to show more code , where does `$jaz` and `$username` comes from.  :

```
if ($_POST['jazyk'] == 'en' && $jaz != '9'){ 
    mysql_query("UPDATE user SET jazyk='en' where name='".$username."' AND id != '$jaz'");
}
```